# Job won't connect to a Kubernetes slave after a second container is configured

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project that uses declarative pipeline to run a Jenkins jobs. It works without issues. At the beginning of the pipeline I have:

```
agent {
    kubernetes {
        defaultContainer 'jnlp'
        yamlFile 'KubernetesPod.yaml'
    }
}
```

and in the yaml file:

```
---
kind: Pod
spec:
    containers:
        -   name: jnlp
            image: <url>/jenkins-slave-selenium:latest
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpu: 4
                    memory: 8G
                requests:
                    cpu: 4
                    memory: 8G
            volumeMounts:
                -   mountPath: /home/jenkins
                    name: cache-volume
                -   mountPath: /home/jenkins/agent
                    name: workspace-volume
                -   mountPath: /dev/shm
                    name: shm
            workingDir: /home/jenkins/agent
    podRetention: never
    volumes:
        -   name: cache-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: jenkins-cache-pvc
                readOnly: false
        -   name: workspace-volume
            emptyDir: { }
        -   name: shm
            emptyDir:
                medium: Memory
    yamlMergeStrategy: merge
    yaml: |
        spec:
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000
    imagePullSecrets:
        - regsecret
```

It works well, but I need to add another container. And I started by just duplication the existing container definition and naming it `jnlp2`.

When I do this, my job won't connect to the slave. The last log lines before is starts waiting are:

```
Pulling image "<url>/jenkins-slave-selenium:latest"
Successfully pulled image "<url>/jenkins-slave-selenium:latest"
Created container jnlp
Started container jnlp
Pulling image "<url>/jenkins-slave-selenium:latest"
Successfully pulled image "<url>/jenkins-slave-selenium:latest"
Created container jnlp2
Started container jnlp2
```

Similarly to what happens with a single container, but it won't connect to the pod.

When I look a the slave's logs I see:

```
Inbound agent connected from 192.168.205.68/192.168.205.68:43156
Remoting version: 4.3
This is a Unix agent
Agent successfully connected and online
```

Can someone please help me to figure out where is the issue?

P.S. I used `<url>` in the configs and logs in place of the company's url

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Comment: @Malgorzata no, I did not. I have a suspicion, that the main container has a JNLP communication setup needed for every Jenkins slave, and maybe Jenkins goes crazy if you have 2 containers with JNLP. But I still have to investigate

Comment: Did you check this Jenkins setup ? Any progress ?